# music libraries

Tags: music, television, copyright

What music libraries your are using? Can you advise some not very pricy ones with rock, ska, raggae, so modern music in good quality?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.5alarmmusic.com/

Answer (score 1):

Search MySpace, Facebook, and other places bands put music and contact them about using their music in whatever project you're working on.  You can possibly get music for cheap or free that way.

Another option is to look for composers that can easily write that stuff for you (for instance, I've played in rock, punk, metal, ska, and reggae bands for the last thirteen years).

Comment: Good point, facebook is for me, the most important music networking tool.  Every artist has a facebook.

Comment: I agree, and a lot of them are looking for ways to get exposed.  

Truth be told, for the genre, if you're looking for something for an out-in-the-open piece, I'd suggest anyone go the existing-band-on-facebook route, though I'd love to score ANYTHING with nothing but ska and reggae.

Comment: In your practice is it possible to find 8-10 artists fast? It's for weekly show.

Comment: Yeah, it's possible.  Most bands check their accounts daily, and will likely already have music recorded that, if they're willing to let you use, they can get you nearly immediately.

Write up a canned email that you can paste as a message to the band.  Make sure to include a section on which songs, in particular, you really liked (you'll actually have to write that every time), and just get to listening and emailing them.

Comment: Thank you I hope my producers will listen to your advise.